# Swift - Adding a navigation bar that overrides the existing one

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have multiple VC's embedded in one NavigationController. 
I have one VC, lets name it VCNotTransparent, that I want the bar to be not transparent, and on other VC's I want it to be transparent.
So in the main VC, I added these lines for making the bar transparent:

```
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

So now all of my bars are transparent in the app.
How can I make VCNotTransparent not transparent without it changing all of the other VC's? one solution I thought of is to add a new navigation bar only in VCNotTransparent, but I do not know how to do that.

EDIT

I also tried embedding VCNotTransparent in its own NavigationController, which works almost, but the issue is that I have navigation from it to some other VC's and they become not transparent as well, since they are sub navigation of the VCNotTransparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle this by enum -

Do below within your MainVC -

```
public enum NavigationType: Int {
case transparent = 1
case notTransparent = 2
}

var currentNavigationType: NavigationType?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.currentNavigationType = .transparent // default
    self.setupNavigationControllerStyle()
}

func setupNavigationControllerStyle (){
switch self.currentNavigationType! {
    case .transparent:
        //do code here for transparent
    case .notTransparent:
         //do code here for not transparent
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

default it will show transparent bar. in which controller you don't want transparent bar just update the `currentNavigationType` property from there like below -

```
class VCNotTransparent: MainVC {

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.currentNavigationType = .notTransparent
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this looks like a good direction for solution, I appreciate it. One thing that is missing for me to mark as accepted is that I do not understand what would be a code for not transparent (inside the func setupNav...). Since I used an empty image to make the background transparent, i am not sure how to revert it to not transparent.

Comment: Try this may be it will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332547/swift-3-how-to-reverse-a-transparent-navigation-bar

Comment: Thanks, it helps a little but it has a problem, when going back to transparent bar from not transparent, the bar only becomes transparent in a delay (even though I placed the changes in the correct functions in the vc life cycle)

Comment: This solution basically makes a lot of weird stuff when moving between the views

Comment: The link you gave, I tried it, but when setting viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear with the solution there, makes the bar black for a second, which is ugly, and sometimes it takes it a second after the view that appears to update to transparent..